# Delete or Reset our current root online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I start migrating our sharepoint on-premisies sharepoint site to sharepoint online, but the migration broke and i am half way. so can anyone advice if i can delete or reset the root site collection, so i can start a new migration? i tried to delete the site collection from the classic admin center, but the delete icon is disabled. as follow:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a Communication site in your tenant, the URL can be anything. Then using the [SharePoint Online PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/), run [Invoke-SPOSiteSwap](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/invoke-spositeswap?view=sharepoint-ps). You can then delete the Archived site (the former root site).

Comment: @Trevore Seward i want the root to be classic team site not communication

Comment: Sorry looks like you can use a classic Team site, too (STS#0).

Comment: but if i use the swap then the site collection will not  be on the root url? is this correct?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the documentation in PoSh is fairly clear in the example.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot delete the root site collection or reset a site collection to its initial status.

As [Trevor Seward](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/6024/trevor-seward) suggests, you can [replace the current root site collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site#replace-your-root-site) with a new site (also known as Site Swap) and then do the migration again.

Please see the detailed steps as following:

1. Create a classic team site in the Classic SharePoint admin center and give it any URL you want, for example, `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/classic`.
2. Replace root site in modern SharePoint admin center:

   a. Select the root site under the **Active sites** list and then click **Replace site** on the menu.

   b. Type `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/classic` in the input box and then click **Save**.

   The original root site will be automatically moved to another URL.

You can also do the Site Swap using PowerShell. Check the documents in Trevor’s reply for the commands.

[image]